# Getting error while passing a parameter in page navigation url

Tags: seam

I created a seam application using seam-gen. I am getting below error while navigating to *StatusList.xhtml* page after saving and clicking **Done** button from *Status.xhtml* form.

**Error is:**

> PWC2785: Cannot serialize session attribute org.jboss.seam.CONVERSATION#21$navigationBean for session 7800870138c191edf3d23718a68e
>
> java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sitestuff.admin.NavigationBean

The following code is written for **Done** button in *Status.xhtml*

```
<s:button id="done" value="Done"action="#{statusHome.viewRecord}"/>
```

and `viewRecord` method is:

```
public String viewRecord() {
    getInstance();
    String rtValue = null;
    if (instance.getTextKey() != null) {
        rtValue = "/StatusList.xhtml?textKey=" + instance.getTextKey() +"?doSearch=1";
    } else {
        rtValue = "/StatusList.xhtml";
    }
    return rtValue;
}
```

I am trying to pass the specific textkey field as parameter in string as I have a filter condition on it and want to show only specific textkey records on *StatusList.xhtml* form.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong and why error occurs ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have Richfaces (I'm assuming you are using it) configured to serialize session state and that "com.sitestuff.admin.NavigationBean" is not Serializable.

Check if that bean/class implements serializable. Something like

```
public class NavigationBean implements java.io.Serializable { ... }
```

I'm also assuming that you have some rule on pages.xml which uses NavigationBean or that you have some interceptors that triggers something on NavigationBean.

I had this problem just recently when playing with the state Serialization, hope that it helps.